# read nsmutablearray at different time intervals

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have this NSMutable array. Reading it one by one after every two seconds and updating textview. But now i want is to read from NSMutable array one by one at different timeintervals than every two seconds. How i can do that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3",@"String4", @"String5",..... nil];  

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(updateText:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];


- (void)updateText:(NSTimer *)theTimer 
    {


        if (index < [myArray count])
        {
            myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
            index++;
        }
        else
            index = 0;
        }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to change the interval value every time the view loads you can try with a random number, in the next example it'll return a random number between 2 and 10:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:arc4random() % 10 + 2
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(updateText:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: cancel the timer each time and recreate it with the desired interval (hang onto a reference to the timer of course).

Answer (score 1):

in your updateText selector just create a new NSTimer with different intervals until there are no more objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay, but using a random delay!

[self performSelector:@selector(updateText:) withObject:nil afterDelay:arc4random()%10+2];